# Make the cursor stay on a specific point

Tags: amcharts

Is there any way to get the ChartCursor to stay on a selected point? 
Especially while using touch-devices it's very uncomfortable, that you have to constantly touch the right data point to see the actual values. Regarding huge datasets the cursor starts to select immediately if you move just a bit and hit the next datapoint. And while you make a selection the cursor disappears.
Is there some kind of workaround to get the cursor stay, where the graph ist clicked/tapped? (Or at least a way to use some kind of threshold for the select?)

Comment: That's a very valid question and request. We're going to add a special property that enables the cursor to stay after click. (PS. I work for amCharts)

Comment: Ok, sounds nice! In addition i would recommend another property, that toggles the fixed cursor to move in dynamic charts. So that you can either choose the cursor to move along with one datapoint and finally move out of the chart, or to stay on a fixed point related to the grid and let the data pass through. (Alternatevly i would recommend you to take a look at the "hairlines.js" plugin for "dygraph" charts, as i'm sure that i would not be the only one, who finds this feature amazingly useful) Please let me know if this request is worth considering for you.

Comment: This is definitely something worth considering. If not as a built in feature then as a standalone plugin. BTW, what you requested is doable using some chart events and showCursorAt() method. I'm writing this down to try out as an experiment/exercise. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Hey. Been a while. We have been discussing this. Just to take it off SO, could you please contact us directly at contact@amcharts.com? Mention this SO thread so we know what it's about. Thanks!